# Dynamic Terms and Conditions based on Product Selection

Tags: checkout, ce-1.9.0.1, onepage-checkout

Is there a way of only showing particular (or all) Terms and Conditions during the checkout process if particular products are in the basket?

I realise that I will need to add an attribute to the products will will indicate whether or not the T&Cs apply, but other than that I don't know where to go.

Comment: You can show it on product details page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone has posted similar question and below link has answer to it.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12567937/magento-have-terms-and-conditions-if-customer-buys-certain-products

Comment: The above solution is great if I want to show ALL terms and conditions if the basket contains specific products. However, I would like to create a selection of terms and conditions, from which SPECIFIC T&Cs are only shown if specific products are in the basket. Is this possible?